# PHP Script not processing

Tags: php

My code is an upload form that redirects all the uploaded files to a PHP processing script. The problem is, after I click "Submit" button, it redirects only to the processing page and stops there, the php page supposedly will process then redirect to another page called selectAlbum.php when upload is successful.

Here is the code for the forms:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title> Sample1  - File Upload on Directory </title>
<style type="text/css">
/* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
#form {
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 520px;
    border-left-width:center;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="form" align="center">
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
        Create an Album (limited to 10 images): <br />
        Album name (Please specify):
    <input type="text" name="album_name" size="30" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile[]"  /><br />
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"   />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code for the PHP PROCESS.  process.php:

```
<?php 

    $target_path = "galleryholder/" .$_POST['album_name']. "/";

    if(!file_exists($target_path))
    {
        if(!mkdir($target_path, TRUE))
        {
            die ("could not create the folder");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['uploadedfile']); $count++)
            {
                $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$count]); 
                $image_size[$count]  = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$count]);

                if($image_size[$count] !== FALSE || ($image_size[$count]) != 0)
                {
                        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target_path)) 
                        {
                        header('Location: selectAlbum.php');

                        } 
                        else
                        {

                            header('Location: uploader3.php');
                        }
                }
                else 
                {

                    header('Location: uploader3.php');
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

When upload is successful it goes here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();

        $('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
    #gallery {
        background-color: #aaa;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 520px;
        background-position:top;
    }
    #gallery ul { list-style: none; }
    #gallery ul li { display: inline; }
    #gallery ul img {
        border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
        border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
    }
    #gallery ul a:hover img {
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #gallery ul a:hover { color: #fff; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

//settings
$column = 5;

//directories

$base = "galleryholder";
//$thumbs ="thumbs";

//get album
$get_album = $_GET['album'];
if(!$get_album)
{
    echo "<b> Select an Album:</b><p />";
    $handle = opendir($base);
    while(($file = readdir($handle))!== FALSE)
    {
        if(is_dir($base."/".$file) && $file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            echo "<a href='$page?album=$file'>$file</a><br />"; //$file. "<br />";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //echo "An album has been clicked.";
    if (!is_dir($base."/".$get_album) || strstr($get_album,".")!=NULL || strstr($get_album,"/")!=NULL || strstr($get_album,"\\")!=NULL)
    {
        echo "The album doesn't does not exist";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2 id='example'><b>$get_album</b></h2><p />";
        echo "<div align='center' id='gallery'>";
        echo "<ul>";    
        $handle = opendir($base."/". $get_album);
        while(($file = readdir($handle))!== FALSE)
        {
            if($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {

                echo "<li>";
                echo "<a href='$base/$get_album/$file'><img src='$base/$get_album/$file' height='100' width='100'>";
                echo "</li>";

            }

        }
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always `die()` or `exit;` after setting a Location header, to stop the script executing further.

Comment: @Kolink thank you for that.. Im still new in those php functions.. THanks by the way! :D

Comment: @Kolink its not working.. still the code is not creating the folder.. T_T what Should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is File Permission. PHP needs 777 for file uploads.

Use unmask() to assign file permisson and then upload.

See below link for unmask  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_umask.asp

and check your mkdir() function the second parameter is mode but you given as TRUE, and create recursive directory.

Refer this link for mkdir() function http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_mkdir.asp

Comment: i already did what you asked me to do.. still got errors.. :( it gives an error on the mkdir side.. how can I resolve this problem?> thanks ahead.

Comment: @SimonCode, I have updated my answer , check your mkdir() function and windows flatform will not support mode

Comment: where can I find the windows flatform mode?

Comment: I think @RobinMichaelPoothurai wanted to say not `flatform` but `platform` and better this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: hahaha.. didn't notice that! anyway do you know where to find it @ZeroSuf3r ??

Comment: @SimonCode http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php read here. `Robin` tryed tell you that `mode` argument ignored in `mkdir`. Text from php.net:
`mode is ignored on Windows.

Note that you probably want to specify the mode as an octal number, which means it should have a leading zero. The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).`

Comment: so it's ok no to have the mode? or should I use the mask to specify the mode to prevent it being ignored by windows..??

Comment: @SimonCode  sorry, I misspelled, it was platform and 'mode' is second parameter. Now remove your 'TRUE' in this code mkdir($target_path, TRUE), It will work.

Comment: @RobinMichaelPoothurai I should remove the TRUE parameter how about the second paramater? how should I deal with it again? umask?

Comment: @SimonCode no. you simply put  mkdir($target_path) and no need to unmask. Run time created directories will have default 777 permissions. You try with simple mkdir($target_path) and second parameter 'mode' is optional.

Comment: BUT should I put the TRUE statement? wait what is the recursive parameter for? its for nested folders right? did I get it right?

Comment: no need to put TRUE statement , simply put mkdir($target_path)

Comment: but my path has a nested folder in it .. is it okay? :D sorry.. just making things sure. :D

Comment: if your path has nested folter, first create folder using mkdir($target_path) and then use unmask in your else condition upto the the last level of directory.