# Why I can not upload files using chmod() in PHP?

Tags: php, upload, chmod

I want to upload an image on a remote host (Everything is ok locally).

I've used the code below like my other previous projects to do it:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["scan"]["tmp_name"], 'images/scans/1.jpg')) {
   chmod ('images/scans/1.jpg','0644');
}
```

But every time I run this code in the internet, I get an error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/profile/Mordent.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

I have to change `scans` directory permission to **0777** and then I can upload images. Otherwise I can not. It's very strange for me. I've used this code in many times in different projects and I had not any problem with it.

Comment: Perhaps this question can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776348/php-script-not-processing

Comment: `chmod()` takes an integer, supplying an integer expressed as an octal held in a string is liable to produce unexpected results. For absolute clarity, you should either pass a decimal integer (as a string if desired/required) or remove the quotes surrounding your octal. I know this is not problem here, because the error you get happens before you reach the `chmod()` but it's still worth noting.

Comment: I did your suggestion and removed quotes. Thank you. But as you said, the problem is still remained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`images/scans/` must be writable by the web server user, and should not need to be `0777`, which is world-writable.  First, `images` must be readable by the web server user, having a `5` in the last position (like `0755`).  The `scans` directory must be owned by the web server user or writable by it.  It is preferable to have it owned by the web server user, where its permissions can also be `0755`.

Comment: I did what you said, but still I have that problem

Answer (score 0):

According to [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php):

> Note: This function will not work on remote files as the 
>   file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

Comment: I believe when the OP says "remote host" he means "production server", as opposed to his own computer.